# wp_nav_menu check both hierarchy fail?

Tags: menus, walker

I see that in menu exist to kind of hierarchy to find the parent and ancestor.

They look for "category or page" hierarchy or for "menu item" hierarchy.

But when both exist in a depth tree branch, they dont work well.

e.q.
IN menu tree

```
• Page 1
  • Category 1
  • Page 2
• Page 2
```

IN admin real hierarchy

`• Category 1 > • Post 1`

• In this case, if I am in (frontoffice) "Category 1" it's parent in menu tree, "Page 1", has class "current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent"

• If I am in Post 1 (frontoffice)  within "Category 1" this one has "current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent". 
But the "Page 1" even if have not direct connection with Post 1, still are parent of "category 1". But it's not marked as Parent or ancestor.

I try by custom walker or even filter the "nav_menu_css_class" to find way that check,

if any child of current is ancestor this is ancestor too. We have to check menu tree or real admin tree, category or page.

Because if level 2 it's ancestor level 1 should be too.

Comment: Inside Category 1 not menu child? Say what? Are you saying IF you are VIEWING a POST inside Category 1, but did not get there via the navigation menu E.g. `Page -> Category 1 -> Post` THEN Page 1 does not show `current-post-ancestor` class, is that correct? Just trying to follow here...

Comment: the menu tree is 'Page -> Category 1' and the 'Post1' are in 'Category 1'. When u are in Post1, the 'Category 1' are highlight but 'Page 1' not

Comment: Ah, you want to highlight all ancestors/parents of a "current menu item" in your nav menu, right?

Answer (score 2):

This is correct behavior as far as I can tell,

Imagine a scenario where you have a menu with top level items, Page A and Page B, each of which have Category 1 attached as a sub-menu item.

### Scenario 1

---

**When viewing** `Post Example X`, **Attached to** `Category 1` **And Where** `Category 1`  appears twice in the menu under different top level items, we see;

```
/*
- Page A              = no ancestor class!
  - Category 1        = current-menu-ancestor, current-menu-parent, current-post-parent
- Page B              = no ancestor class!
  - Category 1        = current-menu-ancestor, current-menu-parent, current-post-parent
*/
```

If you view a **Post**, let's call it `Post Example X`, then which top level menu item should receive the `current-menu-ancestor` class?

1. **Should it be both Page A and Page B?**
2. **Should it be Page A?**
3. **Should it be Page B?**

WordPress decides neither. Its better not to assume what the users intent is unless specified differently, otherwise if you have special styling associated with that class then it would be applied to all top level menu items and beyond causing unexpected results.

But if you say to me that Category 1 only appears beneath Page A top level menu ONLY and no where else, it still doesn't matter... check out these scenarios.

## Scenario 2

---

**When viewing** `Post Example X`, **Attached to** `Category 1` **Where** `Post Example X` does **NOT** appear in the same menu tree as the top level `Page A` or any other top level tree, we see;

```
/*
- Page A              = no ancestor class, still!
  - Category 1        = current-menu-ancestor, current-menu-parent, current-post-parent
- Page B              = not related to post
  - Category 2        = not related to post
*/
```

## Scenario 3

---

**When viewing** `Post Example X` which is also, **Attached to** `Category 1` or in the same tree as the top level `Page A`, we see;

```
/*
- Page A              = current-menu-ancestor
  - Category 1        = current-menu-ancestor, current-menu-parent, current-post-ancestor, current-post-parent
    - Post Example X  = current-menu-item
- Page B              = not related to post
  - Category 2        = not related to post
*/
```

## Scenario 4

---

**When viewing** `Post Example X` which is also, **Attached to** `Category 1` or in the same tree as the top level `Page A` but where `Category 1` also appears beneath `Page B` but itself does not contain our post, we see;

```
/*
- Page A              = current-menu-ancestor
  - Category 1        = current-menu-ancestor, current-menu-parent, current-post-ancestor, current-post-parent
    - Post Example X  = current-menu-item
- Page B              = not related to post
  - Category         = current-menu-ancestor, current-menu-parent, current-post-parent
*/
```

---

I'm just writing this to give a general idea how it works, next I'll take a look at the filters for `nav_menu_css_class` and `wp_get_nav_menu_items`.

My understanding behind the logic of the menu handling process is a bit fuzzy, possibly someone else will jump in and help too in the meantime.

Comment: Yes I follow on trac [some tickets](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12812) I see that is the expected behavior.  

**Scenario 1**  

It happens the same if u have a page duplicate in the menu. All parent are marked. Or if 'PAGE A1' are a 'SUB-PAGE' of 'PAGE A' and in the MENU the 'PAGE A1' are only child of 'PAGE B'
'PAGE A' has class 'current-page-parent'
and 'PAGE B' has class 'current-menu-parent'  


What I expected to be the right behaviour in case of the 'POST X' **Attached to** 'CATEGORY 1' in **Scenario 1**  


is that 'PAGE A' have a class e.q. **current-pseudo-parent-menu**